# Create dataframe from text file

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a text file `sample.txt` like

```
someText someText 
COLUMN1: value1, COLUMN2:value2, COLUMN3: value3
COLUMN1: value11, COLUMN2:value22, COLUMN3: value33
someOtherText someOtherText
someOtherText someOtherText
COLUMN1: value111, COLUMN2:value222, COLUMN3: value333
```

What's a good way I can create a dataframe with headers COLUMN1, COLUMN2 and COLUMN3 and put all values from above text to the corresponding columns

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a specific issue? Have you tried anything? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

I would start by cleaning the data, I mean, filtering the txt file so it contains only your future records

```
COLUMN1: value1, COLUMN2:value2, COLUMN3: value3
COLUMN1: value11, COLUMN2:value22, COLUMN3: value33
COLUMN1: value111, COLUMN2:value222, COLUMN3: value333
```

If you know this lines will contain only these words (and in the same order), its a good point to start.
Next thing will be a formatting one, remove all 'COLUMN...:' with some regex and then you have a csv file which can be loaded to frameworks like pandas, spark...

```
value1, value2, value3
value11, value22, value33
value111, value222, value333
```

Just remember that the ordering is important on this approach.
Another way would be tranformig to a json file in a very similar way:

```
{'COLUMN1': 'value1', 'COLUMN2': 'value2', 'COLUMN3': 'value3'}
```

Quoting column names is mandatory, but values may vary depending on its type.